# Jquery - Re-Open Dialog after Postback Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have list to be deleted, and when user clicks it, it shows jquery ui dialog with "Confirm" and "Cancel" buttons

When user clicks "Confirm" it'll call ajax function and give it postback

and I want to close the dialog after that,so i used command `$(this).dialog("close");`
and it works as expected.

But now when I delete the other list the UI dialog doesn't appear.

how can I solve this?

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                bgiframe: true,
                width: 300,
                height: 150,
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false
            });


            function submit_delete(y,z){ //kirim data lewat ajax

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'delete_page.php',
                    data: {fte:y,tipe:z},
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(z==1){
                            var divv= '#container_table1';
                        }  else if(z==2){
                            var divv= '#container_table2';
                        }   else if(z==3){
                            var divv= '#container_table3';
                        }   

                        $(divv).html(data);//window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
                         $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                    }
                })
                return true;
            }
            //end submit ajax onclick training



            $(".c_del1").click(function(){
                var cc= ($(this).next().val());
                var c=cc.split('#')
                alert(cc);
                $("#dialog").text('Do You Want to Delete '+c[1]+"?");

                var yy = $(this).prop('id');


                $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
                    "Confirm" : function() {

                        submit_delete(c[0],1); 

                    },
                    "Cancel" : function() {                            
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                });

                $("#dialog").dialog("open");


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `on` or `live` while calling click event

```
$(".c_del1").on('click',function(){

                --------------------


            });
```

or

```
$(".c_del1").live('click',function(){

                --------------------


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind only first element. Try this:

```
$(".c_del1").each(function(n,el){
  $(el).click //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function submit_delete(y, z) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delete_page.php', type: 'POST',
                data: { fte: y, tipe: z },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (z == 1) {
                        var divv = '#container_table1';
                    } else if (z == 2) {
                        var divv = '#container_table2';
                    } else if (z == 3) {
                        var divv = '#container_table3';
                    }

                    $(divv).html(data);
                    //window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000);
                    $('.DeleteDialog').dialog("close");
                }
            });
        };

        //function Deletemessage(id, obj) { };
        //Or
        function Deletemessage(obj) {
            var c = ($.trim($(obj).next().val())).split('#');

            $('<div class="DeleteDialog"></div>').appendTo('body')
                    .html('<div><h6>Do You Want to Delete ' + c[1] + '?</h6></div>')
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                        width: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                //$(obj).removeAttr('onclick');

                                submit_delete(c[0], 1);

                                //$(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            Cancel: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
        };


        <!--<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="Deletemessage(1,this);" />-->  
       //Or
        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="c_del1" onclick="Deletemessage(this);" />
```